# JSF2: add ui:include to binding object's children

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `UIComponent` that is binded to a backing bean. I'd like to add a child to the component that corresponds to the `ui:include` tag, through my backing bean's init method.

for example:

```
<p:tab>
    <ui:include src="/page.xhtml" />
</p:tab>
```

I want to create this in my backing bean like:

```
<p:tab binding="${bean.tab}" />
```

So basicly i'm looking for the corresponding UIComponent class for the ui:include, so i can add this as a child to my tab property.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I'm now trying with faceletContext.includeFacelet :)

Answer (score 1):

i have read this thread 20 time and i couldn't find the solution at first so here are my additional comment for it after i found the right way:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FaceletFactory defaultFactory = ApplicationAssociate.getInstance(facesContext.getExternalContext()).getFaceletFactory();
Facelet facelet = defaultFactory.getFacelet(xhtmlUrl);
```

Then i have created a FaceletHandler to add the component.

Another solution was :

```
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) facesContext.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
faceletContext.includeFacelet(parentComponent, xhtmlUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's working :) Get the faceletContext from facescontext:

```
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
```